# jquery input file missing text

Tags: php, html

When I get the text from a input element that has the type of file

```
$("#selected-file").val() or .text()
//only returns the name of the file selected. not the entire path
```

how can I get all of the text from the element?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get the full local path of a file. (*for security reasons*)

Also it is not much use, since you do not have access to the local maching..

Comment: The overall goal I have is to allow users to upload an image.
What is disallowing users to do so though a php post?

Comment: @drake, why do you want the local path to the file ? you just need the filename and the path on your server, where your code stores the uploaded file..

Answer (score 0):

It is based upon the browser.  you have to use some user defined function to get filename.

try by spliting the url by / and get the last array element.